# directory name is invalid when saving csv to 3 seperate locations

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, copy, sys

I am trying to save to multiple locations but get the error message below.

```
    files = os.listdir(path)
NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'C:\\Users\\ze\\ga.csv'
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
    import sys, os, time, shutil
    print(time.ctime())
    path = 'C:\\Users\\ze\\ga.csv'
    files = os.listdir(path)
    files.sort()
    for f in files:
        src = path+f
        dst = 'C:\\Users\\ze\\ga.csv' +f
            dst2 = 'C:\\Users\\ze\\ga.csv' +f
            dst3 = 'C:\\Users\\ze\\ga.csv' +f
        shutil.move(src, dst)
    print(time.ctime())
```

Comment: `'C:\\Users\\ze\\ga.csv'` is the path to a directory?

Comment: I was going to say "maybe Windows doesn't accept directory names with periods in them", but when I tried it on my Windows 10 box, it worked fine... Curious.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Fair point.   I want to transfer from ga.csv -> new locations.  It does not like C:\\Users\\ze\\ga.csv

Comment: @Kevin It does?  For me it doesn't recognise the csv existing I want to transfer.  Maybe I'm missing an import or something

Comment: I'm overlooking something.  Why don't I just use simple VBA for this task.  Silly me.. sometimes.

Comment: Clarification: when I say "it worked fine" I mean I successfully created a folder named "ga.csv". I didn't try running your code so I don't know one way or the other whether it works.

Answer (score 1):

I have few python scripts where I also faced the same problem and I have modified the path like below which fixed my problem.

```
  path = "C:/Users/ze/ga.csv"
```

Comment: Does not work for me.  I might try re-writing it as Python does not like this at all.

Comment: I am using Python version 3.4 and it is working fine with me.

Comment: I'm using Anaconda 3.6 version.  Yeah that's super strange.  Just gives directory invalid no matter where I put the file.

Comment: Also verify the path properly if there is any spelling mistake.